# How to use a variant dictionary (`a{sv}`) in dbus-send

Tags: types, signature, dbus

I have some trouble with `dbus-send` when using `a{sv}`

Calling a method with `in_signature='a{ss}'` seems to work using the 
following command line:

```
dbus-send --dest="org.test.TestService" 
/org/test/TestService/object org.test.TestService.method1 dict:string:string:"a","1","b","2"
```

Now I would like to have a dictionary with a variant type for values 
(`in_signature=a{sv}`),

How can I use it in `dbus-send`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Although D-Bus supports signatures such as `a{sv}`, dbus-send does not. This is from the [dbus-send man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dbus-send):

> D-Bus supports more types than these, but dbus-send currently does not. *Also, dbus-send does not permit empty containers or nested containers (e.g. arrays of variants).*

So as far as I can understand it, you cannot send a dict of string:variant using dbus-send.

Comment: Oh, ok, so one cannot, for instance, simulate a call to `notify-send` by writing a more verbose call to `dbus-send`, because the former wants arguments of type `susssasa{sv}i`.

Answer (score 21):

#### Not possible with `dbus-send`

As mentioned, `dbus-send` does not support all Dbus types. From [dbus-send man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dbus-send):

> Also, dbus-send does not permit empty containers or nested containers (e.g. arrays of variants).

---

#### But possible `gdbus`

Buried in https://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/docs/2012.5/gio/gdbus.html we see this:

```
gdbus call --session \
           --dest org.freedesktop.Notifications \
           --object-path /org/freedesktop/Notifications \
           --method org.freedesktop.Notifications.Notify \
           my_app_name \
           42 \
           gtk-dialog-info \
           "The Summary" \
           "Here's the body of the notification" \
           [] \
           {} \
           5000
```

**Bonus**: this method returns the id, so you can close or replace the notification.

Comment: André, downvoting this because the example is not for sending a `(a{sv})` argument. And that is what the question is all about because for trivial arguments, `dbus-send` is enough.

Comment: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/359944) explains the syntax of `a{sv}` arguments to `gdbus`:

    "{'String': <'variant_value'>, 'String2': <'variant_value'>}"

Answer (score 2):

You need to compile dbus-send with the following patch.

https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/#/c/12323/2/sys-apps/dbus/files/dbus-1.4.12-send-variant-dict.patch

FYR, I uploaded the patched full source at this link.

https://gitlab.com/mujicion/dbus-send.git

Comment: You might be able to improve your post by specifying **how** to apply the patch.

Comment: Putting a random patch somewhere on the internet without submitting it to the upstream D-Bus project benefits very few people. Please do not promote this kind of answer unless the patch has also been submitted, reviewed and accepted upstream.

Answer (score -2):

I compiled the new version of dbus-send but still has an issue for sending a{sv}.Can you pl provide the syntax for this

Comment: Did you read this question answers??!