# How to set a variant array with dbus-send?

Tags: dbus

making this query:

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.ofono /he910_0 org.ofono.ConnectionManager.GetContexts
```

I get the following structure:

```
array [
  struct {
     object path "/he910_0/context1"
     array [
         dict entry(
           string "AccessPointName"
           variant                   string "mobile.vodafone.it"
        )
       ....
        dict entry(
           string "Settings"
           variant                   array [
              ]
        )
     ]
  }
```

I'd like to set "Settings" property with dbus-send messages. I tried with:

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.ofono /he910_0/context1 org.ofono.ConnectionContext.SetProperty string:"Settings" variant:array:string:"Interface=ppp0","Method=dhcp"
```

But I receive:

```
dbus-send: Unknown type "array"
```

So, the final question is: how to set a variant array through dbus-send ?

Comment: Any idea how to display the array contents, perhaps as numbers or hex?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do this with `dbus-send`, but you might be able to do what you want with the quite similar tool `gdbus`. See [how to use parameters signature as "a{sv}" in dbus-send](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8846671/how-to-use-parameters-signature-as-asv-in-dbus-send?rq=1)

Comment: Indeed. As per `man dbus-send`: “dbus-send does not permit … nested containers”; a variant containing an array is a nested container.