# Is there a "repeat action every n time units" action?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, io-monad, hoogle

[Upon refining the Haskell notification server I'm experimenting with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78077358/why-do-i-get-unexpected-reply-type-from-notify-send-when-using-this-haskell-no), I come up with something like this:

```hs
import Control.Concurrent (threadDelay)
import Control.Monad (forever)
repeatEvery :: Int -> IO () -> IO ()
repeatEvery time action = forever $ action >> threadDelay time
```

which can be used like this

```hs
repeatEvery oneSec $ do
  stuff
```

and I was wondering if `repeatEvery` is exposed by some library.

I haven't found anything like that on [Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/) by searching for `a -> f b -> f b`, but maybe the signature is slighly different?

Comment: Depending on how important regularity is, you may want to correct for drift due to time spent in `action` and imprecision of waking up after a `threadDelay`.

Answer (score 2):

[Control.Concurrent.Async.Every.every](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/every-0.0.1/docs/Control-Concurrent-Async-Every.html#v:every)